# How to change a Simple Product to a Bundle Product

Tags: magento-1.7, database, sql, bundled-product, product-type

I tried doing the below SQL on Magento CE v1.7 to change a Simple Product to a Bundle Product, but after I run the update, the price also shows as 0 and it doesn't let me edit the price on the Product-->Price tab (it's always set as Dynamic price and the price field is non-editable).

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity SET type_id = 'bundle', has_options = 1 where sku = <Simple Product SKU>
```

Any ideas how to resolve this? I need to update a bunch of simple products to be bundled products, but am always facing this issue.

Comment: Please take your time to accept an answer if it helped you. http://magento.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas how to resolve this? I need to update a bunch of simple products to be bundled products, but am always facing this issue.

There are reasons that you cannot  change the product type of existing products as well as the price type of bundles. So expect side effects and inconsistencies if you do.

That being said, you can change it with this query:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_int v
    INNER JOIN catalog_eav_attribute a
    ON a.attribute_id=v.attribute_id
SET v.value=1
WHERE a.attribute_code='price_type'
    AND v.entity_id=<ID>
```

with `<ID>` being the product id (not SKU). The value `1` stands for "fixed", and `0` for dynamic (default)